# Are there any infinite series which we know converges but do not know what it converges to?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We have many ways of determining whether a series converges or diverges and we also have many series that we don't know the convergence there of. However, are there any series which we do know converges, but not what it converges to?

Comment: I think an example would be:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157371/does-this-have-a-known-closed-form

Comment: Arguably, $1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \ldots$, the series for $e$, converges but we do not know what it converges to. We know it's a number between $2$ and $3$, indeed, between $2.718$ and $2.719$, but as for *knowing* it? I'd say that we don't. On the other hand, we sure know a lot **about** it. If you want a better answer than that, you're going to have to say what "knowing" means, which isn't exactly mathematics.

Comment: Let me add that what we "know" is closely linked to what we're familiar with. The Greeks didn't know about irrationals for some time, and regarded them as horrible monsters. (Presumably they hadn't been able to prove the irrationality of pi, or they've have had to reconsider.) The number $e$ is pretty weird...until you study calculus and work with it for a while, and then it's 'nice' and 'known', and we pick a new letter of the alphabet to reserve for it, like $\phi$ for the golden ratio.

Comment: There are uncountable many real numbers. The decimal fractions representing them can be considered as convergent series converging to them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example, take $e=1+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\cdots.$ Now take some ridiculously [big number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth's_up-arrow_notation), say $x:=3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow \uparrow 3$ and try to evaluate $x\cdot e=x+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x}{3!}+\cdots$. While we know the answer is $xe$, to get the first digit is equivalent to finding the $x$'th digit of $e$, which is probably impossible given how big $x$ is.

Another example is (see Theorem 2 from [On Equalities Involving Integrals of the Logarithm of the Riemann $\zeta$-Function and equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/159151550.pdf)): take the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function: $\rho_k:=\sigma_k+it_k$. Prove that:

$$0=\sum_{\rho: \sigma_k\geq 1/2,t_k>0}\left(\frac{1}{\sigma_k^2+t_k^2}-\frac{1}{1/4+t_k^2}\right),$$

which is equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis (notice the sum will be positive if the hypothesis is false). Note that the series must converge regardless.

Comment: Hm. That is a valid answer, however I feel as though it is a bit... contrived (if that makes any sense?).

Comment: Upvote for the second example. The first one doesn't really feel like a good example to me.